# BackgroundTask not firing in C# Application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am working with Windows Phone 8.1 and C#.

By following Microsoft's MSDN sample (available at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) to create an audio player, I tried to integrate it into my project. However, while the code works fine in Microsoft's sample, it does not work as intended after I integrate it into my project.

I'll copy and paste the files are likely to contain the issue. `Constants.cs`, `ApplicationSettingsHelper.cs` and `MyPlaylistManager.cs` remain the same as in the sample (which you can look at by clicking the link above and hitting the "Browse code" tab).

When I run the following project, it throws the following error: "Background Audio Task didn't start in expected time". If I change the `bool result = SererInitialized.WaitOne(2000);` block of code (in `StartBackgroundAudio()` to `bool result = true;`, it simply prints "Background Audio Task initialized" in the console and then stops.

**Page.xaml.cs**

http://pastebin.com/L2zxzJKv

**BackgroundAudio.cs**

http://pastebin.com/zR6uzBf3

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I ended up undoing all my changes and simply use the exact same code from the sample in the project. I added the extensions in the appmanifest.

**I have created a sample project to help someone solve the problem and answer this question. You can find it at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ED2ED8732D8D457E!132&authkey=!AFBrZi5oI3k2zmU&ithint=file%2czip**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ZIP file you provided only has one project in the solution. The background audio task needs to be its own separate *Windows Runtime Component* project in the solution. Please look at the sample solution again and make sure that you have set up your solution correctly.

The reason why your background audio task needs to be in a separate project is because all background tasks need to be in a separate project, and background tasks will run in a separate process than your foreground app. This is so that if the OS suspends or terminates your app (i.e. you switched to another app) then your background audio task will continue to run and play audio even though your app has been suspended. You will then need to communicate between the background audio task and foreground process by passing messages between the processes (see [`SendMessageToForeground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.sendmessagetoforeground.aspx) and [`SendMessageToBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.sendmessagetobackground.aspx)).

Apps will always be suspended by the OS when put in the background, therefore you need a separate lightweight background task process that has special permission to run in the background for the purpose of playing music.

These pages are quite helpful at explaining all of the concepts:

- [Overview: Background audio (Windows Phone Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx)
- [How to play audio in the background (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the backgroundaudiotask file HAS to be in a separate solution. Is that the reason this is not working? Also, why does it have to be a different solution?

Comment: The background audio task needs to be a separate *project* in your *solution*, not as a separate *solution* (solutions contain multiple projects).